cupy.linalg.solve for positive definite matrix?
It seems like cupy.linalg.solve doesn't have an option for me to solve linear system Ax=b assumingA is positive definite?
I am looking for something like scipy.linalg.solve where one can actually tell the method to assume the matrix is positive definite which would then solve more efficiently, such as using cholesky decomposition.
I might be able to manually decompose
then use lu solve but I do wonder if I missed a built-in, streamlined solution.
